# Visual Studio 2019 C# code colours in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I have a question. I need to use `VS 2017` in my work but i love `VS 2019` code colouring. It is so much easier to read. My question is did someone seen some code colours themes like `VS2019`/`VS CODE (JavaScript)` themes?

Or there is easy solution, for example import code colours from `VS2019` to `VS2017`?

Thanks for help

Comment: use vs2019 then

Comment: Not all nugets work with VS2017, for example `StyleCop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can personalize your VS2017 with the "Color Theme Editor" extension available on the Visual Studio Market Place for free.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor

**EDIT :**

For Syntax Highlighting you can choose in the gallery here :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=tag%3Asyntax%20highlighting&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=vs15&sortBy=Relevance

Answer (score 3):

Use color coder https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xellarix.ColorCoder

extension

also, you can customize the color for different types

Answer (score 2):

I use VS2019 as my personal IDE but for my company labtop I still use 2017 because they provide professional license.

I want to have the same text color theme on my both IDE for consistency and I found this extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StanislavKuzmichArtStea1th.EnhancedSyntaxHighlighting

This theme is pretty similar to the theme when you enable "use enhanced colors for c# and basic" in VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this is a new feature in the C# and VB language editors - in other words, these are new features/settings in VS2019 that simply don't exist in VS2017.